# Cannot resolve symbol @Configuration in spring webmvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I am creating a Spring MVC project in Intellij and when I have created `WebConfig`class, the `@Configuration` annotation is not recognised by Intellij and it gives "Cannot resolve symbol" error. Even though I have used "import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration" but it could not recognise "springframework" either. Can someone help me with this.

[image: Screenshot of my project in Intellij]

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>academy.learnprogramming</groupId>
    <artifactId>Todo-list</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <annotation-api.version>1.3.2</annotation-api.version>
        <servlet-api.version>3.1.0</servlet-api.version>
<!--        <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>-->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
                <version>${annotation-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>edge</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${basedir}/libs/lombok-1.18.12.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <release>${java.version}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>tomcat9x</containerId>
                        <type>embedded</type>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: YOu apparently don't have the needed dependencies in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: show us the pom.xml

Comment: I have added these dependencies in pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

`@Configuration` belongs to module `spring-context-${spring.version}`. Make sure it appears among dependencies. Since in maven dependencies can be transitive, consider using:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see which dependency brings the required jar.

When you're done, re-import the maven project into intelliJ so that the IDE will update its internal indices

Comment: I have added this dependency but still @Configuration annotation is not recognised by Intellij.



 <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: Run mvn clean test from the command line to localize the issue - if it works - Intellij is out of sync, if it fails - there is an issue in your pom

Comment: mvn clean test fails saying "fatal error compiling". What could be the issue in pom? Please suggest.

Comment: Make sure you understand the difference between dependencies and dependencyManagement sections. I believe you shouldn't use dependencyManagement here.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I removed the dependency management tag and it worked for me.

Comment: How to use `spring-context-${spring.version}` in `Gradle` project

Comment: I believe just the same way I've explained for the maven. Both Maven and Gradle are build systems, and spring being a runtime framework doesnt really care how exactly the application artifact was built.